# VScode lags on powerful PC

Tags: ide, visual-studio-code

VSCode Version: 1.20.1

OS Version: Windows 10 Home 64-bit

It has occured since a first-time clean installation. Every action (Input, selection, scrolling) has a small but very noticeable amount of lag (approx. 0.5s lag) every 10 or so seconds. This occurs on newly created empty files as well. CPU usage is normal (<5%) and RAM usage is normal (250mb).

PC Specs:
Intel Core i7-7700HQ 2.80GHz
8GB DDR4 RAM
Samsung 256GB SSD
(Nvidia GTX1060 GPU)

Does this issue occur when all extensions are disabled?: Yes

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its already tracked by an issue https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/44919

Comment: I have this problem too, haven't you found any solutions to it?